# Java Servlet System.out.print

Tags: java, servlets

I'm new to this whole HTTPServlet aspect of Java, and was curious on how to get started. I essentially want to put a URL into a form and show some indication of receiving the URL / grabbing it and passing it into a jSoup method later on. Whenever I console.log() anything in the doPost method, nothing shows up so I have no clue how to even know if I've grabbed the URL successfully. Below is my Java code and my HTML form:

```
 protected final void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException {

 }
```

Form:

```
    <form method="POST">
    <h3> Insert URL Here </h3>
    <input type="text" name="url">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go To URL">
    </form>
```

Comment: I don’t think this question pertains to applets

Comment: Applets are dead, and hand-writing servlets hasn't been the way to do things for 20 years. Use a framework like Spring MVC with Thymeleaf (if you're doing traditional HTML forms) instead and let it handle all of the tedious boilerplate for you.

Comment: How do you `console.log()` in Java? How did you define `console`?